# Add JSON key names to json values in an array. File contains bulk JSONs

Tags: python, java, arrays, json

I have a file that contains list of jsons (more than 10k), something like this

```
{"name":"abc", "location": {"coordinates": [-94.350096,39.049484]}} 
{"name":"xyz", "location": {"coordinates": [-91.350096,36.049484]}} 
{"name":"lmn", "location": {"coordinates": [-84.350096,69.049484]}} 
{"name":"pqr", "location": {"coordinates": [-90.350096,31.049484]}}
```

I want to convert this to following

```
{"name":"abc", "location": {"coordinates": ["latitude":-94.350096,"longitude":39.049484]}} 
{"name":"xyz", "location": {"coordinates": ["latitude":-91.350096,"longitude":36.049484]}}
{"name":"lmn", "location": {"coordinates": ["latitude":-84.350096,"longitude":69.049484]}} 
{"name":"pqr", "location": {"coordinates": ["latitude":-90.350096,"longitude":31.049484]}}
```

Any reference to any such code?

Comment: if only the words "latitude" and "longitude" need to be added then this can be added with notepad++ editor. 
if you want the results with programming, please tell.

Comment: Your example is not valid JSON. Only objects (`{}`) have keys.

Comment: @Pran Sukh - I have MAC. Either way is fine, programming or a tool that mac supports

Comment: @user837593 i just created a video over youtube. here is the link https://youtu.be/nXYQEEePuSI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the file line by line and load it as `dict` using `json` module. Finally, edit it as required.

```
import json
with open("test.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        data = json.loads(line)
        coords = data["location"]["coordinates"]
        data["location"]["coordinates"] = {"latitute": coords[0], "longitude": coords[1]}
        print(data)
```

Comment: Note that this answer only prints lines of `json` format data to the console. However, this can still be piped to a new file.

Comment: @Eshwar S R - Thank you very much for your inputs. I am new to Python. Can "json.loads(line)" load 733MB size of a file. It has 85k records. If not whats the right way

Comment: We are not loading the whole file once for all. We are loading each line, which is a json by itself.

Comment: I have 85k lines in the file. I am trying to modify each line and then write it to a file. It stops at 2130 line number and gives below error. "  File "json_replace.py", line 9, in <module>
    coords = data["location"]["coordinates"]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable".
 Code that I tried based on comment above is edited in below comment

Comment: ```import json

jsonFile = open("locator_latlong.json", "a")
i=0;
with open("locator.json") as f:
    for line in f:
        # print(line)
        data = json.loads(line)
        coords = data["location"]["coordinates"]
        #  print(coords);
        data["location"]["coordinates"] = {"latitude": coords[0], "longitude": coords[1]}
        i=i+1;
        print(i, data)
        jsonString = json.dumps(data)
        jsonFile.write(jsonString)
        jsonFile.write('\n')
jsonFile.close()```